# I am trying to build BST in python from scratch RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am trying to build tree from scratch but getting Maximum recursion error.
Kindly, Help me to find the error.

First i created a node and with make_node function, i am trying to build tree.
then with the help of inorder function i am trying to print the data in the node.

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None;
        self.right = None;

class tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = None;
    def make_node(self,data):
        if(self.start==None):
            self.start = node(data)
            print(self.start.data)
            return
        
        #temp = self.start
        if(self.start.data<data):
            if(self.start.left == None):
                print(self.start.left.data)
                self.start.left = node(data)
            else:
                self.start.left(self.make_node(data))
        elif(self.start.data>=data):
            print(self.start.right.data)
            if(self.start.right == None):
                self.start.right = node(data)
            else:
                self.start.right(self.make_node(data))
    
    def inorder(self):
        #temp2 = self.start
        if(self.start==None):
            return
        self.start = self.start
        self.inorder(self.start.left)
        print(self.start.data)
        self.inoder(self.start.right)
        

BST = tree()
BST.make_node(2)
BST.make_node(3)
BST.make_node(4)
BST.make_node(5)

BST.inorder()
```

Can you guys help me to find my mistakes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Errors I have found:**

**1.** You can't call the function like this:
**self.start.left(self.make_node(data))**. As **self** refers to the object of the tree, not an object of the node. *For referencing Node object you can pass as a parameter.* So, I have rectified this error everywhere in your code.

**2.** Also, you have used ***inequalities in opposite order*** i.e. larger element on the left side of the root and smaller element in the right... which I have changed in the code below.

**Node Class:**

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None;
        self.right = None;
```

**Tree Class:**

```
class tree:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = None;
    
    def make_node(self,Node,data):
        
        if(Node == None):
            Node = node(data)
            if(self.start == None):
                self.start = Node
            return Node
        
        if(Node.data>data):
            Node.left = self.make_node(Node.left,data)
        elif(Node.data<=data):
            Node.right = self.make_node(Node.right,data)
            
        return Node
    
    def inorder(self,root):
        if(root==None):
            return
        self.inorder(root.left)
        print(root.data)
        self.inorder(root.right)
```

**Building a tree and using inorder Function:**

```
BST = tree()
BST.make_node(BST.start,2)
BST.make_node(BST.start,3)
BST.make_node(BST.start,4)
BST.make_node(BST.start,5)

BST.inorder(BST.start)
```

Comment: @Harsh You're welcome. It has been my pleasure to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the recursion limit with sys.getrecursionlimit:

`import sys print(sys.getrecursionlimit())`

then change the limit with sys.getrecursionlimit():

`sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)`

Comment: there is no issue related to system settings... as Author is only adding a few elements... See my answer it worked without any error...